# Magento 2.4 error

Tags: magento2.4, installation

I have installed magento, now when i try to access it below error appears.

> [2021-09-22 11:20:36] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access
> denied for user 'root'@'localhost' {"exception":"[object]
> (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception(code: 1698): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access
> denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at
> /var/www/html/m24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144,
> PDOException(code: 1698): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for
> user 'root'@'localhost' at
> /var/www/html/m24/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128)"}
> []

Comment: please check password you have used for user root in app/etc/env.php. try to direct connect database form CMD

Answer (score 0):

You must configured Magento2 with wrong password. take look at " app/etc/env.php. "

here check your password and try to login in phpmyadmin with that password.